# Different steps when clicking range elements compared to dragging them

Tags: javascript, html, range

I want to specify different steps for clicking range elements. It should be possible to drag the slider to any value, as default, but to only reach specific values with a click, for instance, "30" and "70". If a user clicks on any value on the range track, he should automatically end up at "30" or "70", depending on where he clicked (closer to 30 or 70). Is there a way to implement something like this with HTML or Javascript? I only managed to accomplish something similar for both clicks and drags, using the following code:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="30">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this with event handlers. Since mouse drags and clicks send some of the same events, you can distinguish them by checking variations on mouse position between events.

```
<body>
    <input id="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100"/>
</body>
<script>
    // Keep track of coordinates on mouse down event
    var x = 0, y = 0;

    // Avoid adjusting value from slight mouse movement on click
    var delta = 5;

    function savePosition(e) {
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
    };

    function adjust(e) {
        if (Math.abs(x - e.pageX) > delta || Math.abs(y - e.pageY) > delta) {
            // Drag detected: Keep current value
            return;
        }

        // Click detected
        var newValue = 30;
        if (e.target.value > 50) {
            newValue = 70;
        }
        e.target.value = newValue;
    };

    var el = document.getElementById('slider');
    el.addEventListener('mousedown', savePosition);
    el.addEventListener('mouseup', adjust);
    el.addEventListener('click', adjust);
    el = undefined;

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Clicking behavior works fine now, however, it is not possible to drag the slider to every value anymore (only 30 and 70). Dragging the thumb should not be affected. Is there any fix for that?

Comment: Yes, I've corrected it. Basically you need to distinguish drags from clicks by checking variations on mouse position between events.